# CSS only affecting first image in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The goal is to make everything with the class "baPics" to have 266px of max width.

**The problem is that as it is right now, only the first image in each row is being affected by the class.**

It works if I use an inline CSS for each image but that's inefficient.

I'm using bootstrap as my framework.

Here is my HTML

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="3u"></div>
                        <div class="7u">
                            <img class="baPics" src="images/graft1.jpg" alt="">
                            <img class="baPIcs" src="images/graft2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="3u"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="3u"></div>
                        <div class="7u">
                            <img class="baPics" src="images/ivan1.jpg" alt="">
                            <img class="baPIcs" src="images/ivan2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="3u"></div>
                    </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.baPics {
    max-width: 266px;
}
```

Comment: The first one is `baPics` and the second one is `baPIcs`, with a capital i. Copy and paste is your friend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img class="baPics" src="images/graft1.jpg" alt="">
<img class="baPIcs" src="images/graft2.jpg" alt="">
```

Note the class names are different, should be

```
<img class="baPics" src="images/graft1.jpg" alt="">
<img class="baPics" src="images/graft2.jpg" alt="">
```

without the capital i (I).